# set_exception_handler is not working with PHP CLI?

Tags: php, exception, command-line-interface

Did I missed something in the php doc?

I have set a `set_exception_handler` on my `index.php` to caught exception (from librairies) and avoid PHP Fatal Error for uncaught exception.

When I run my script with Apache I have no problem (the function wich caught the exception works correctly).
BUT when I try with PHP cli (`php -r 'include "index.php";'`), I get the PHP fatal Error.

Any idea?

-- index.php

```
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
throw new Exception("Test exception");

function exception_handler($e) {
    echo '-- excemption handler --';
    $toLog = '['.date('d/m/Y H:i:s').'] '.$e->getMessage()."\n".$e->getTraceAsString();
    var_dump($toLog);
}
```

Comment: How about showing your code?

Comment: This is a very odd problem which will bite people who occasionally use `php -r` to test out a snippet. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run your code you should use

> php index.php

This will not show fatal error.

When you running

> php -r 'include "index.php";'

its actually executing the statement as php script. And this script it self not subject to handle its own fatal error.

Comment: Yes, no more error but in my script, i need to pass var to the index.php... That's why i used `php -r`. I can try to pass my var with a other way (like `php index.php args`).